# How come my method isn't my method dropping a table that exists?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have method that checks whether a table exists, and if it does, it drops it and then recreates it. Else, it creates the table. It is done using this method because I **have** to do it like this for my assignment.

I have a print statement that tells me that that the table does exists (it prints if inside the `if statement` that checks whether it exists). I then get an error saying:

> Could not create table(s) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Positon: 12

**The method:**

```
public static void createTable(Connection conn, String name, String description) {
   PreparedStatement pst = nul;
    Statement st = null;

    String SQL = "drop table ?; create table ?";

    try {
        if (tableExist(conn, name)) {
            System.out.println("Works");
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.setString(2, description);
            int update = pst.executeUpdate();
        } else {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("create table " + description);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create table(s) " + e);
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can not pass identifiers (= table names) as parameters in JDBC you need to concatenate the table names into your SQL string.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

- Use `drop table if exists`
- `executeupdate` is for one statement.
- You cannot pass identifiers as parameters, so you have to munge the query string.

So, issue two statements:

```
"drop table if exists <table name>"
"create table . . . "
```

Comment: Certain JDBC drivers actually _do_ allow executing multiple statements via `executeUpdate()`, though even so, it is best design to use separate statements even in that case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Though true, the JDBC API is intended to execute one statement at a time.  Multiple statements is non-standard (and for drivers that support it, usually needs to be enabled explicitly).

Comment: You can't pass identifiers as parameters in JDBC